Which output bit is the MSB on the sn74ls590N
Product datasheet: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74LS590N/377749
I am having some trouble reading this. From what I can gather, a low g input allows the outputs to be 0/1 and the counter has an active low enable and active low reset.
The output bits are given as A-H but the sheet doesn't state their weightings. From the logic diagram, it appears that output H is the most significant bit but im not sure and would appreciate some help. Thank you.

If you look at the logic diagram on page 2 of the data sheet you linked, \$Q_A\$ is the LSB. There is a cleaner data sheet for the SN74HC590A on TI's web site. Nexperia has a better data sheet showing a timing diagram on page 5.

Thanks, that's how I thought I should read it but I wasn't sure.
